# XML view with relative percentages

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been creating Android apps for well over 2 years, I've created games and animated live wallpapers as well as using some basic XML to create some settings. I've mainly used my own custom views written in JAVA using the canvas class. Now I want to move across to XML views because of the speed of development it offers.

Anyhow, I'm trying to figure out how to create an Android XML view using percentages of the screen instead of DP.

Link to what I'm trying to say:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/raj0c.png

What would be the best way of doing this? And can someone give me an example? It needs to have the same percentages on every screen it's displayed on.

Comment: may I ask why you don't want to use dp values? This is pretty much the same because dp takes the device's density into account. And a margin of 20dp will look the same on any device

Comment: Because on long devices or wide devices with different aspect ratios the DP screws up and makes the app look naff.

Comment: I would suggest looking into using layout_weight for your views.

Comment: @OllyDixon well as far as I know there's no direct way to use percentages in XML (one possibility is the weight as said above). But you could get the device's screen width, calculate your percentages basing in this value and apply LayoutParams to your Views

Comment: It's a shame we can't just use percentages in XML, would be far more simple and effective. Thanks for this advice, it's what I though I might have to do.